# How do I write a function that blocks the button until the checkbox is activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function that blocks the button until the checkbox is activated.
But, the function does not find the checkbox.
Please, tell me, what am I doing wrong?

```js
function simpleFunc(checkName, aName) {
  $(document).on('change', "[name=checkName]", function() {

    var e2 = $(".card__link").attr('name', aName);
    e2.addClass('probka2');

    if (this.checked) {
      e2.addClass('btn_active');
      e2.removeClass('btn_passive');
    } else {
      e2.addClass('btn_passive')
      e2.removeClass('btn_active');
    }


  });
}
```

```html
<div class="card__container">

  <div class="img__container">
    <img src="/lorem-pict.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="text__container">
    <h2 class="card__title">
      <a href="" class="card__title-link">name</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="card__descr">description</p>
    <form name="forma1" action="" class="card__form">
      <input class="ch1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="check" onClick="simpleFunc(ch1, f1)" ;>
      <label for="">I agree with the terms of the offer </label>
    </form>
    <div class="btn__container">
      <a href="" name="f1" class="card__link btn">details </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Firstly, what button? There isn't one in your HTML. Also, there is no `name=checkname` element in the HTML.

Comment: Hello,

I apologize for misleading everyone.

I mean
     <div class = "btn__container">
       <a href="" name="f1" class="card__link btn"> details </a>
     </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>You don't need the function call onClick if your bind the change event. You can modify your code like below.</del>

<del>If checkbox is checked then removed the disabled attribute and if not then add the disabled attribute which will prevent the button from clicking. You can apply css class also on top of that.</del>

Create a function which will accept the checkbox name and anchor link name as arguments, call this function in checkbox onClick event handler.
Based on that you can disable or enable individual card anchor link.

Note: for disabling anchor I am using 'pointer-events: none' css .

```js
function activateLink(checkName,linkName){
  var checked =  $('[name='+checkName+']').prop("checked");
  if (checked) {
    $('[name='+linkName+']').removeClass('disableClick');
  } else {
    $('[name='+linkName+']').addClass('disableClick');
  }
}
```

```css
.disableClick{
    pointer-events: none;
    color:grey;
}

.btn__container {
padding:15px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card__container">

  <div class="img__container">
    <img src="/lorem-pict.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="text__container">
    <h2 class="card__title">
      <a href="" class="card__title-link">name</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="card__descr">description</p>
    <form name="forma1" action="" class="card__form">
      <input class="ch1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="check" onClick="activateLink('check','f1')" ;>
      <label for="">I agree with the terms of the offer </label>
    </form>
    <div class="btn__container">
      <a href="www.google.com" name="f1" class="card__link btn">details </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card__container">

  <div class="img__container">
    <img src="/lorem-pict.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="text__container">
    <h2 class="card__title">
      <a href="" class="card__title-link">name 1</a>
    </h2>
    <p class="card__descr">description 1</p>
    <form name="forma1" action="" class="card__form">
      <input class="ch1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="check1" onClick="activateLink('check1','f11')" ;>
      <label for="">I agree with the terms of the offer </label>
    </form>
    <div class="btn__container">
      <a href="www.google.com" name="f11" class="card__link btn">details </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have updated the answer based on your use case, please check.

Comment: Thank you!

The fact is that on the page I have several cards.

Each card has a checkbox and a button ( ... tag).

Comment: That can be done also, Do you to perform these actions for each individual cards?

Comment: Dear Vimal Patel, thank you very much!
You helped me a lot!